# Hints for nested context managers in a Python 2.6- / Python 3-neutral way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.6, contextmanager

I have been using a lot of context managers as a clean way of composing various setup/teardown situations.  Since my deployments target Python 2.6, this means using `contextlib.nested`.

Lately I've been interested in supporting both Python 2.x and Python 3 with the same code base.  This has been possible with [some projects](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz), but I'm running into trouble in the case of context managers because:

1. `contextlib.nested` isn't supported in Python 3
2. Python-3 style nested context managers (e.g., `with aa() as a, bb() as b: ...`) aren't supported in 2.6.

There is a basic syntactic incompatibility here.  For various reasons beyond my control, 2.7 may be difficult to get into production for now, but I'd like to future-proof the code as much as possible, hence the Python 3 interest.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for supporting nested context managers in the same code base for 2.6 and 3.x?  Or is this a lost cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> This function has two major quirks that have led to it being deprecated. Firstly, as the context managers are all constructed before the function is invoked, the `__new__()` and `__init__()` methods of the inner context managers are not actually covered by the scope of the outer context managers. That means, for example, that using `nested()` to open two files is a programming error as the first file will not be closed promptly if an exception is thrown when opening the second file.
>
> Secondly, if the`__enter__()` method of one of the inner context managers raises an exception that is caught and suppressed by the `__exit__()` method of one of the outer context managers, this construct will raise `RuntimeError` rather than skipping the body of the with statement.

Thus in almost all cases the correct answer is JBernardo's. It's a bit more indenting but it's a bit less buggy, too.

Comment: Upvote, that's helpful, I should have RTFM more closely.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure people who are smarter than me have already thought of this, but I'm wondering why these issues can't be avoided by writing `nested` recursively, so that each manager really is called within a nested scope.

Comment: @asmeurer: The issue isn't the scope, it's the way `__exit__()` works. There's a long discussion of the problem and various potential solutions in the python-dev archives if you want to search for it. But the conclusion was that it was better to drop it than to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Just nest them

```
with aa() as a:
    with bb() as b:
        #some code here
```

Comment: That works fine for a couple deep.  But I have some more lengthy combinations (integration tests) which are much cleaner when composed together in a single statement.

Comment: @JohnJ If you really want `contextlib.nested` grab the [source code](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/contextlib.py#l88) and paste in your project.

Comment: @JohnJ: If you actually have a dynamic list of context managers, then you _do_ need something like `nested`—although even then, you can write something that's simpler and less quirky if you don't need to handle all the edge cases `nested` tried—and failed—to handle.

Comment: @JohnJ: On the other hand, if you have a static but large collection of them, consider writing a wrapper contextmanager that takes care of that particular collection explicitly, then you only need a simple `with` statement.

Comment: Yes, I've done that before, and will apparently be doing more of that given @Veedrac's answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the quirks of `nested` that Veedrac mentioned aren't an issue for you, you can just copy the [code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/32de3923bb94/Lib/contextlib.py) from the Python standard library.

If they do bother you, then your only choices are to manually nest them, or to drop Python 2.6 support. It really doesn't matter if you use two code-bases or one for this. If this is the case, then the *only* way it will work in Python 2.6 would be to nest them. I guess you could play with writing some kind of custom 2to3 fixer that translates your unnested 2.7 code into nested 2.6 code. But honestly, it will be less painful to just use a single code-base with nested managers until you can drop 2.6 support.

Answer (score 1):

You can always reimplement `nested` on your own and keep it in a `compatibility.py` file within the project.  This is often what is done to cross versions.

Edit:  I see that @JBernardo already mentioned this solution in a comment.